# Push new branch upstream

Tags: egit

I have a local repository and a remote repository on Github. I just created two new local branches, *Documentation* and *Development*, using *origin/master* as the upstream source.

How do I push these new branches upstream. I have made no changes in the new branches yet so there is no new content, simply the branches themselves.

Right now I want to create a new topic branch using *origin/Development* as the upstream but it is not there yet.

Comment: Why would you have documentation and development (i.e. code?) on separate branches? Or did you mean to have them on the same branch, perhaps under different directories?

Comment: This is a new project and I am currently working on the documentation of the justification for keeping documentation separate from code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any new commits on the branch to do a push.  The key for creating and tracking corresponding branches on the remote is using the `--set-upstream` flag.

```
$ git checkout -b Documentation
$ git push --set-upstream origin Documentation
```

Short flag form:

```
$ git checkout -b Documentation
$ git push -u origin Documentation
```

Comment: I am trying to do this using egit, not git.

Comment: The `Push Wizard` gives  a more step-by-step walk-through to achieve the same result: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Push_Wizard